# C++ Write Message Error

Tags: c++, function

I am new to C++, and I am creating a quick application, and to make life easier, I created a writeMessage(string message) function.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Calculator {
public:
    static double add(double num1, double num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    static double subtract(double num1, double num2) {
        return num1 - num2;
    }

    static double multiply(double num1, double num2) {
        return num1 * num2;
    }

    static double divide(double num1, double num2) {
        return num1 / num2;
    }
    static void writeMessage(string message) {
        cout << message << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Calculator.writeMessage("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error that says

> ||=== Build: Release in Calculator (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\Users\Beta\Desktop\Calculator\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>   C:\Users\Beta\Desktop\Calculator\main.cpp|29|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Help?

Comment: It should be `Calculator::writeMessage("Test");`

Answer (score 2):

Simple syntax error.

Use

```
Calculator::writeMessage("Test");
```

instead of

```
Calculator.writeMessage("Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

calculator is currently your class.  you could write

```
calculator::writemessage("this is a message");
```

or you could declare a variable of type calculator

```
calculator c;
c.writemessage("this is a message.");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/), to access a static function you need to use

```
::
```

So your main would look something like this instead:

```
int main()
{
    Calculator::writeMessage("Test");
    return 0;
}
```